# Removing children in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my DB model I have 4 entities: Order, Service, Client, Employee.
Their relations:

Client 0..1 - * Order

Order 1 - * Service

Employee 1 - * Service.

I attempt to remove all Services in specific Order but I get an InvalidOperationException:
*The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.*

Here is my code:

```
        public static void ClearSevicesInOrder(int orderId)
        {
            using (DbEntities context = new DbEntities())
            {
                var o = context.Orders.Find(orderId);
                o.Services.Clear();
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a blog post about this, with a possible solution.
http://wimpool.nl/blog/DotNet/extending-entity-framework-4-with-parentvalidator

In short: To make it work you have to delete every service in the Services list

Comment: Thanks in advance!
My code:
                    foreach (var item in context.Services.Where(s => s.OrderID == orderId))
                    {
                        context.Services.Remove(item);
                    }
                    context.SaveChanges();